# How to compress a tar file in a tar.gz without directory?

Tags: python, gzip, tar, tarfile

I'm looking for a way to compress a tar file in a tar.gz without directory.

Today my code generate a TAR file without directory with "tarfile" library and arcname arguments but when I want to compress this TAR file in TAR.GZ I don't understand how to delete directory.

I have made many tests in the last 3 days.

My code :

```
Tarname = example.tar
ImageDirectory = C:\...
TarDirectory = C:\..

tar = tarfile.open(Tarname, "w")
tar.add(ImageDirectory,arcname=TarName)
tar.close()

targz = tarfile.open("example.tar.gz", "w:gz")
targz.add(TarDirectory, arcname=TarName)
targz.close()
```

Comment: I do not understand the question.  What are you getting, and what is it that you want to get instead?  Note that `arcname` is not referring to the name of the archive, but rather the name of the entry being added in the tar file.  Why are you making `example.tar`, and then `example.tar.gz`?  That will just make two different files.

Comment: Hello Mark, I try to group tif and txt files in a TAR file and then compress this one in a tar.gz file. For all files, I don't want to conserve the original directory. Am I understandable ?

Comment: Finally I want a TARGZ\TAR\TIF directory but my files are not in the same directory that I use to work and I am forced to pass the files directory which stay in my final archives...

Answer (score 4):

For individual **file(s)**:

```
tar.add(file, arcname=os.path.basename(file))
```

for each file that you want to add.  `basename` will strip the directory information.

Or, for a recursive **directory**:

```
def flatten(tarinfo):
    tarinfo.name = os.path.basename(tarinfo.name)
    return tarinfo

tar = tarfile.open("example.tar.gz", "w:gz")
tar.add("directory", filter=flatten)
tar.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, basename don't works but for your second proposition what is "name" and could you precise when tarinfo is a function of tarfile library and when it's a variable (TarInfo and tarinfo for example)

Comment: Did you `import os.path` for `basename`?

Comment: You can read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html) for `tarinfo` and `tarinfo.name`.

Comment: filter don't exist in my python version :(

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: I'm on 2.5 version and I must conserve it.

Comment: 2.5 has `os.path` and `basename`.  So the first example I gave will work.  You will just need to do the recursion through directories yourself instead of depending on `add` for that.  Use `listdir` to list the contents of the directory, and iterate through that to `add` files.

Comment: Hi ! Sorry but I don't understand, could you explain me with an example please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the gzip module :
Here is an example of how to use it :

```
import gzip
f_in = open('file.txt', 'rb')
f_out = gzip.open('file.txt.gz', 'wb')
f_out.writelines(f_in)
f_out.close()
f_in.close()
```

Comment: Yes, I have ever tried before but same result. The directory is ever in final tar.gz. There is no arcname in gzip ?

Comment: He's already using `"w:gz"` when writing the tar file, so he doesn't need the gzip module.