# Python tar.add files but omit parent directories

Tags: python, python-2.7, tar

I am trying to create a tar file from a list of files stored in a text file, I have working code to create the tar, but I wish to start the archive from a certain directory (app and all subdirectories), and remove the parents directories. This is due to the software only opening the file from a certain directory.

package.list files are as below:

`app\myFile
app\myDir\myFile
app\myDir\myFile2`

If I omit the path in `restore.add`, it cannot find the files due to my program running from elsewhere. How do I tell the tar to start at a particular directory, or to add the files, but maintain the directory structure it got from the text file, e.g starting with `app` not all the parent dirs

My objective is to do this `tar cf restore.tar -T package.list` but with Python on Windows.

I have tried `basename` from here: [How to compress a tar file in a tar.gz without directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137539/how-to-compress-a-tar-file-in-a-tar-gz-without-directory), this strips out ALL the directories.

I have also tried using `arcname='app'` in the .add method, however this gives some weird results by breaking the directory structure and renames loads of files to `app`

```
path = foo + '\\' + bar
file = open(path +  '\\package.list', 'r')
restore = tarfile.open(path +  '\\restore.tar', 'w')
for line in file:
    restore.add(path + '\\' + line.strip())
restore.close()
file.close()
```

Using Python 2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use 2nd argument for [`TarFile.add`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.add), it specified the name inside the archive.

So assuming every path is sane something like this would work:

```
import tarfile
prefix = "some_dir/"
archive_path = "inside_dir/file.txt"
with tarfile.open("test.tar", "w") as tar:
    tar.add(prefix+archive_path, archive_path)
```

Usage:

```
> cat some_dir/inside_dir/file.txt
test
> python2 test_tar.py
> tar --list -f ./test.tar
inside_dir/file.txt
```

In production, i'd advise to use appropriate module for path handling to make sure every slash and backslash is in right place.

Comment: Thank you! worked well once I tweaked it slightly for my other code. I took a look at the TarFile.add method before posting but didn't realise you could add a 2nd arguement!

Comment: Maybe a simpler and more elegant solution here ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/74978118/3223785 ). 